# Google analytics get the total pageviews of one URL plus same URLS with get parameters

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I am currently getting my data like this:

```
      $result = Analytics::performQuery(
            Period::days(7),
            'ga:pageviews',
            [    
                'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
                 'max-results' => $maxResults,
                 'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
                'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=~/blog*'
            ]
        );
```

The response delivers multiple pages with the same slug like:

/blogs/article1

/blogs/article1?ref=homepage

and so on.

In order to get all the pageviews I currently **explode** the URL at the get parameter then in a **foreach loop** I get the total pageviews like this:

```
$article = Analytics::performQuery(
                    Period::days(7),
                    'ga:pageviews',
                    [    
                        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
                            'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
                        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$result['url']
                    ]
                );
```

then I get the total pageviews with `article['totalsForAllResults']['ga:pageviews']`

This obviously ends up making many google requests, which have a daily limit. Is there a way to get the total pageviews of one URL plus all the URLs that have the same name and get parameters attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total number of pageviews (intended as a single number) just don't define the dimension `'dimensions' => 'ga: pagePath'` in the request.